# angular form to model

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i am having a generic Angular component which has form property and a method for retrieving form value as proper type, and i want to avoid simple casting to T, and want to instantiate the form value to proper type

can any one provide a good example on how to to this?

```
export class ClassA {
  propS: string;
  propD: string;
  constructor(data: ClassA) {
    this.propD = data.propD;
    this.propS = data.propS;
  }
}

export class ClassB {
  propF: number;
  propK: ClassA;
  constructor(data: ClassB) {
    this.propF = data.propF;
    this.propK = new ClassA(data.propK);
  }
}


export class ClassC<T> {
  form: FormGroup;

  getFormValue(): T {
    this.form.value as T;
  }
}

export class ClassQ extends ClassC<ClassB> {
  testData!: ClassB;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
    'propF': ['']
    'propK': fb.group({
        'propD': [''],
        'propS': ['']
    })
  });

  this.testData = super.getFormValue();
  }


}
```

the issue i am facing is that testData is of type ClassB but propK is Object...

Thanks